# Issue with [mochawesome] addContext within Mocha.Testfunction

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Want to add extra context into mocha testfunction, but the addContext doesn't work.

```
describe('Test', function () {
    before('before', function () {
        addContext(this, 'context before all'); <-- Not working
      }); 
    after('after', function () {
        addContext(this, 'context after all'); <-- Not working
      }); 


it('Call just a working test API', function () {

    var test=this;
    addContext(this, 'Hello1 (this) !!!!');            <-- Working
    addContext(test, 'Hello2 (test) !!!!');            <-- Working
    unirest.post('http://mockbin.com/request')
    .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 
    'application/json'})
    .send({ "parameter": 23, "foo": "bar" }).end(function (response) {
        console.log('In reponse function');
        addContext(test, 'Hello3 !!!!');            <-- Not working
        addContext(test, '' + response.body);       <-- Not working
    });
});
});
```

As you all can see, a very simple index.js, and indeed a test-report is generated.
But 4 out of 6 addContext are missing.
Hopefully somebody knows the answer??

Comment: Facing the same problem. could anybody help here pls

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add `done` as a parameter inside your `it` blocks and then call `done();` just before the closing `it` block.

Here's a snippet of example code from the official **mochawesome** npm package GitHub repo:

```
describe('Test Suite with Context', () => {
    it('should have text context', function (done) {
      (1 + 1).should.equal(2);
      addContext(this, 'this is the test context');
      done();
    });
}
```

Here's where I go that code from:
https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome/blob/master/test-functional/test-context.js

**Let me know if this works.**